# Remove debuild buildsystem=cmake linker flags

Tags: dpkg, cmake, mingw

I'm trying to create a *.deb file from debian using cmake with a mingw cross-compiler.  CMake's compiler test fails when using `dpkg-buildpackage`.

Building normally is fine:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr 
         -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON 
         -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=None 
         -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR=/etc 
         -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCALSTATEDIR=/var
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /etc/alternatives/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /etc/alternatives/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /etc/alternatives/i686-w64-mingw32-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /etc/alternatives/i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

However when I build this using `dpkg-buildpackage` it fails to configure:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source package foo
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source version 1.0
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source distribution stretch
dpkg-buildpackage: info: source changed by $USER
dpkg-buildpackage: info: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build hw
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean --buildsystem=cmake --parallel 
   dh_testdir -O--buildsystem=cmake -O--parallel
   dh_auto_clean -O--buildsystem=cmake -O--parallel
   dh_clean -O--buildsystem=cmake -O--parallel
 dpkg-source -b hw
dpkg-source: info: using source format '3.0 (native)'
dpkg-source: info: building sim-honeywell-ease-control in sim-honeywell-ease-control_1.0.tar.xz
dpkg-source: info: building sim-honeywell-ease-control in sim-honeywell-ease-control_1.0.dsc
 debian/rules build
make: 'build' is up to date.
 fakeroot debian/rules binary
dh binary --buildsystem=cmake --parallel 
   dh_testdir -O--buildsystem=cmake -O--parallel
   dh_update_autotools_config -O--buildsystem=cmake -O--parallel
   dh_auto_configure -O--buildsystem=cmake -O--parallel
    cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=None -DCMAKE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR=/etc -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCALSTATEDIR=/var
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /etc/alternatives/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /etc/alternatives/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:51 (message):
  The C compiler "/etc/alternatives/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc" is not able to
  compile a simple test program.
```

The interesting part of the full log is a failure during linking:

```
/etc/alternatives/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2   -Wl,-z,relro  -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/cmTC_fc912.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o cmTC_fc912.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_fc912.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles/cmTC_fc912.dir/linklibs.rsp
/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: unrecognized option '-z'
```

The mingw linker fails to recognize the `-z` option.  When I `diff` the CMakeCache.txt, I can see that dpkg-buildpakcage adds some linker flags by default:

```
< CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=-Wl,-z,relro
---
> CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=
```

How can I prevent `dpkg-buildpackage` from doing this?

FYI: my `debian/rules` file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
%:
    dh $@ --buildsystem=cmake --parallel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable the `relro` hardening configuration; change your `debian/rules` to

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

export DEB_BUILD_MAINT_OPTIONS = hardening=-relro

%:
        dh $@ --buildsystem=cmake --parallel
```

See [the `dpkg-buildflags` manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/dpkg-dev/dpkg-buildflags.1.en.html) for details.

(As an aside, if you’re using compat level 10 or greater, you don’t need `--parallel` since it’s enabled by default. In many cases you can drop `--buildsystem=cmake` too since `dh` will auto-detect it.)

Comment: I'm at compat 9 (still in stable), and you are right about auto-detecting `--buildsystem=cmake`.  About the main issue, the suggested solution works perfectly. That's the third time you've helped me quickly. I think I owe you a beer by now.

Comment: I always like helping people who are trying to do the right thing, and you get bonus points for using my MinGW-w64 packages on top of that ;-).

Comment: I saw that you were the maintainer for that!  I really appreciate your work.